# Does anyone perform routine maintenance on Data?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

On the *Enterprise-D*, the Engineering department try to make sure that most (if not all) machinery are working efficiently by conducting routine checks and maintenance. **Data is also *technically* a machine, does anyone ever check him?**

I'm assuming he has sensors which would indicate if something was wrong which he could then decide to repair himself or go to Engineering. But the sensors *could* somehow malfunction and say that all systems are go when in fact it is not. Isn't there someone that does a routine check on him just to be extra sure that Data is fine?

Comment: I recall an episode where Data went to see Doctor Crusher and her reaction was essentially "I really don't know how to help you; maybe you should talk to Geordi." Can't remember *which* episode, though

Comment: @JasonBaker - Thanks for mentioning that, I will see if I can find that episode :)

Comment: “Data is also *technically* a machine” — racist!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Hehe!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Data performs his own maintenance

[Data's Day](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/185.htm)

> DATA [OC]: I am rarely in need of Doctor Beverly Crusher's professional services as **my bio-mechanical maintenance programme is self sufficient**.

The Star Trek Encylopedia explains the biomechanincal maintenance program as:

> Software incorporated into Commander Data's positrnoic network.  It kept him physically healthy and rarely in need of Dr. Crusher's professional services

[A Fistful of Datas](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/234.htm)

> DATA: And **I will perform a self-diagnostic**

As is later seen in that episode (A Fistful of Datas) we see that Data can connect to the computer which can perform a diagnostic on him also.

The quote from Data's day, however, does seem to indicate quite strongly that, unless something is seriously awry (as Xantec points out, was the case when Geordi performed a diagnostic on Data in *Clues), **Data performs his own routine maintenance.**

Because I anticipate someone asking, no Dr Soong did *not* perform maintenance on Data in *Brothers*; you will note he does the same thing with the teeth to Lore and straight after both instances, both Data and Lore are 'awakened' if you will, from their unconscious state.

Comment: Had a feeling you would be the one to answer this! Thank you :)

Comment: Geordi likely assists Data with his maintenance, when needed/requested. In the episode *Clues* Picard has Geordi run a diagnostic on Data to determine why he is acting peculiar.

Comment: @Xantec - That's a great piece of info, thank you!